# Is there a CSP for Intune to configure Screensaver Timeout?

Tags: mdm, intune

I've been looking for a while through the Intune and CSP documentation for a way to configure the screensaver timeout on our managed Windows 10 devices.

I'd like to set it to X minutes where X is 5 in some cases and 15 in others.

Doesn't look like it exists yet, from what I can see.

I expected it to be under Policy CSP or Personalization CSP but I couldn't locate it there.

Answer (score 0):

Profiles > Endpoint Security -> Local device security options -> Interactive Login -> Minutes of lock screen inactivity until screen saver activates